# Contract method is not found

Tags: nearprotocol

So I'm working out of `index.ts` where my contract code is and `utils.js` where I added my methods and I'm testing my functions in the console but receive the above response.

`index.ts`

```
import { Context, logging, storage, PersistentMap } from 'near-sdk-as'
import { string } from 'prop-types';

// Key value pair
// Value = array ; Key = voter ID
let votersReg= new PersistentMap<string, bool>("Voters Registration");
let candidateReg= new PersistentMap<string, i32>("Candidate Registration");

// Context.sender == 'usernmae.testnet'

export function addVote(candidate:string):i32{
    if(!votersReg.contains(Context.sender)){
        votersReg.set(Context.sender, true)
        if(!candidateReg.contains(candidate)){
            candidateReg.set(candidate, 1)
        }
        else{
            let currentCount=candidateReg.getSome(candidate);
            currentCount += 1;
            candidateReg.set(candidate, currentCount);
        }  
    }
    else{
        logging.log("You have already voted!")
    }
    return candidateReg.getSome(candidate)
}

export function getVotes(candidate:string):i32{
    if(candidateReg.contains(candidate)){
        return candidateReg.getSome(candidate)
    }
    else {return 0}
}
```

`utils.js`

```
import { connect, Contract, keyStores, WalletConnection } from 'near-api-js'
import getConfig from './config'

//const nearConfig = getConfig(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
const nearConfig = getConfig('testnet')

// Initialize contract & set global variables
export async function initContract() {
  // Initialize connection to the NEAR testnet
  const near = await connect(Object.assign({ deps: { keyStore: new keyStores.BrowserLocalStorageKeyStore() } }, nearConfig))

  // Initializing Wallet based Account. It can work with NEAR testnet wallet that
  // is hosted at https://wallet.testnet.near.org
  window.walletConnection = new WalletConnection(near)

  // Getting the Account ID. If still unauthorized, it's just empty string
  window.accountId = window.walletConnection.getAccountId()

  // Initializing our contract APIs by contract name and configuration
  window.contract = await new Contract(window.walletConnection.account(), nearConfig.contractName, {
    // View methods are read only. They don't modify the state, but usually return some value.
    viewMethods: ['getVotes'],
    // Change methods can modify the state. But you don't receive the returned value when called.
    changeMethods: ['addVote'],
  })
}

export function logout() {
  window.walletConnection.signOut()
  // reload page
  window.location.replace(window.location.origin + window.location.pathname)
}

export function login() {
  // Allow the current app to make calls to the specified contract on the
  // user's behalf.
  // This works by creating a new access key for the user's account and storing
  // the private key in localStorage.
  window.walletConnection.requestSignIn(nearConfig.contractName)
}
```

testing `addVote()` with `await window.contract.addVote({candidate: "dummy"})` returns

```
Failure [dev-1605381216128-9269896]: Error: Contract method is not found
printLogsAndFailures @ account.js:62
signAndSendTransaction @ account.js:132
async function (async)
signAndSendTransaction @ account.js:77
signAndSendTransaction @ wallet-account.js:159
async function (async)
signAndSendTransaction @ wallet-account.js:151
functionCall @ account.js:223
(anonymous) @ contract.js:47
addVote @ contract.js:14
(anonymous) @ VM77:1
errors.js:19 Uncaught Error: Contract method is not found
    at Object.parseRpcError (rpc_errors.js:38)
    at ConnectedWalletAccount.signAndSendTransaction (account.js:139)
    at async ConnectedWalletAccount.signAndSendTransaction (wallet-account.js:159)
    at :1234/async http:/localhost:1234/src.e31bb0bc.js:48839
    at :1234/async <anonymous>:1
```

testing `getVotes()` with `await window.contract.getVotes()` returns

```
json-rpc-provider.js:69 Uncaught Error: Querying call/dev-1605381216128-9269896/getVotes failed: wasm execution failed with error: FunctionCallError(MethodResolveError(MethodNotFound)).
{
  "error": "wasm execution failed with error: FunctionCallError(MethodResolveError(MethodNotFound))",
  "logs": [],
  "block_height": 24423413,
  "block_hash": "96FXs7Y2a53uvfpuJhm9eU8asjNicf87SbqwFGvmBn6K"
}
    at JsonRpcProvider.query (json-rpc-provider.js:68)
    at async ConnectedWalletAccount.viewFunction (account.js:276)
    at :1234/async <anonymous>:1
```

I am not exactly sure what is going on here. I was under the impression I did not need to deploy my contracts prior to testing, perhaps this is what is screwing things up but I thought deploying contracts was a finality step. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You do need to deploy your contracts in order to test them. You will have to do this for each function you add for it to be available in the frontend.

Comment: Under the README.md for create-near-app -> https://github.com/near/create-near-app/tree/master/templates/react it reads "Every smart contract in NEAR has its own associated account. When you run npm run dev, your smart contract gets deployed to the live NEAR TestNet with a throwaway account. When you're ready to make it permanent, here's how." Does this not imply that I am able to test methods simply with npm run dev? Or must I work through steps 1,2, and 3 and run ```npm run deploy```? thaks