# npm run deploy failure

Tags: npm, blockchain, smartcontracts, nearprotocol

This is a followup to my previous post -> [Contract method is not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64852672/contract-method-is-not-found;) I am now attempting to pass npm run deploy however, it seems to be failing with the following.

````
//helper.testnet.near.org, file: ./out/main.wasm
An error occured
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './out/main.wasm'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:476:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:377:35)
    at exports.deploy (/Users/User_Name/Desktop/nearTest/testVote/node_modules/near-cli/index.js:42:49)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Object.handler (/Users/User_Name/Desktop/nearTest/testVote/node_modules/near-cli/utils/exit-on-error.js:39:9) {
  [stack]: "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './out/main.wasm'\n" +
    '    at Object.openSync (fs.js:476:3)\n' +
    '    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:377:35)\n' +
    '    at exports.deploy (/Users/User_Name/Desktop/nearTest/testVote/node_modules/near-cli/index.js:42:49)\n' +
    '    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)\n' +
    '    at async Object.handler (/Users/User_Name/Desktop/nearTest/testVote/node_modules/near-cli/utils/exit-on-error.js:39:9)',
  [message]: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './out/main.wasm'",
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: './out/main.wasm'
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [create-near-app](https://github.com/near/create-near-app) it expects, as this error suggests, that the generated binary be located at `./out/main.wasm`.  Currently there is a script, `compile`, and it creates a symbolic link from the binary to `out/main.wasm`, which either the debug or release. The following [line](https://github.com/near/create-near-app/blob/e6aab4a95e6d3653fb61a677f2173206da89a10d/common/contracts/assemblyscript/compile#L35) in the script is hard coded to expect the name `greeter.wasm`.

```js
`./build/${debug ? 'debug' : 'release'}/greeter.wasm`
```

So my guess is if you have renamed the project and it is silently failing.  Until we fix this issue, try changing the above to the name of the generated wasm file.

Comment: How do I know what the generated wasm file's name is? Also, I'm a little confused as I open the out folder and see main.wasm inside of it.

Comment: I think I've found the issue is that main.wasm exists in my out folder but is not being registered somehow? Basically, if I go in to finder on my mac and search the directory I see the main.wasm file in the out directory. But, if I look in VS code through the file tree main.wasm does not exist in the out folder and I also can not create new files in the out folder? Something buggy is happening.

Comment: You should be able to see the file in `build/(release/debug)/` folder.  As mentioned the new changes to create near app create a symbolic link to the file.  This might also be the culprit.  So you could try locating the file in the build directory and copying it into `out` renaming it `main.wasm`.  Can you `cd` into the out directory?